# Propagation of delete on vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

If I `delete` a vector of pointers, is `delete` called on the pointers within it?  For example:

```
vector<Obj *> v = new vector<Obj *>();
v.push_back(new Obj());
delete v;
```

After this, is the `Obj` deleted as well?

Comment: Imagine you said `{ Obj x; v.push_back(&x); }`. Would what you asked make any sense at all?

Answer (score 5):

When the vector is destroyed it destroys each of the contained elements. Pointers don't do anything when destroyed and so the memory is leaked and `delete` is not called on them individually.

A better solution is to use `std::unique_ptr`

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj> >
```

`unique_ptr` will delete the object it points to when it is destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not.  If you think about how the vector works it makes sense.  A vector allocates memory dynamically to store its elements and then copies them in.

It has no idea what its type is, so when it calls `delete` on its internal memory store it is calling delete on the memory used to store *each pointer*, not what the pointers refer to.  For example, if you had written something like...

```
int **a = new int*[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    a[i] = new int(i);

delete [] a;
```

`a` is deallocated, but what about the memory that each pointer refers to?  It is leaked; you only deallocated the memory used to store the pointers themselves.  Even if it did attempt something like you are asking you wouldn't want it.  How could the vector possibly know if the memory referred to by a given pointer is safe to call `delete` on?  It can't.

This is why you shouldn't use a vector of pointers. Instead, prefer a vector of smart pointers, i.e.,

```
std::vector<unique_ptr<my_type>> vec;
```

Comment: *"It has no idea what its type is"*. What do you mean - it absolutely knows the type it is storing.

Comment: @Pubby: No, it doesn't.  It is a templated type, the underlying type could be anything, the actual code is only generated at compile time.  It cannot know that it needs to treat its memory store differently when `T` is a pointer type, nor could it do so in a sane way. It could not possibly know how the memory that a given pointer refers to was allocated, so it can do nothing more than `delete [] _my_buffer;`

Comment: It possible for vector to have different destruction semantics (such as call `delete` if the type is a pointer) with a simple partial specialization. Templates know what their type is. In the case of vector, the decision was made for it to use the same destruction semantics for all types (besides bool!) and so that is why it is the way it is. (Sorry if this is just silly pedantism!)

Comment: @Pubby: Right, so it *could* specialize... but it doesn't, so what I said is true.  I think you're talking about templates as a feature while I'm talking about `std::vector<T>`.  However, we could argue further because you say that *"Templates know what their type is"* which is only true for a specialization. In general, if you create a type `my_type<T>` with no specializations and then ship that code you have no idea what T will be, ever, so you cannot program for it.  Of course you know what is for a specialization, that's the whole point...

Comment: You can program for it without specializing the class itself by using stuff like type traits and type conditionals. Anyway, I think we're on the same page, have an upvote.

Comment: @Pubby: :D Fair enough, one back atcha

Comment: Alright I guess I'll enter the fray then: this sentence is wrong to me "It has no idea what its type is" and I still don't get it after what you and Pubby said. How does `std::vector<>` not know what type it's storing? It's `T`. If it didn't know that, it couldn't contruct things.

Comment: @GManNickG: Of course, `T` is not a type in and of itself, it could be anything... perhaps I didn't convey my intent very well.  What I meant by that is that the vector doesn't perform any special processing given the type of `T`.  It treats all `T`'s the same, so it doesn't special case a pointer type (and of course, it wouldn't make sense to do so anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you should iterate through the vector and delete the elements inside it.

Comment: Well, he *should* avoid using pointers altogether and use smart pointers instead.

Comment: Without knowing the circumstances it is not good to give the idea that using managed pointers is the ONLY thing to do. I agree it's good to mention, which is why I think your answer is better, but I think it is more important to actually answer the question, which is that one should delete the elements in the vector before deleting the vector. Circumstances I can think of where using managed pointers are impossible include: homework where you are restricted to using standard libraries, programming contests (where this question actually matters to avoid memory errors), etc.

Comment: But you can do both (answer the question and help someone who doesn't know any better by providing a better, alternative solution).  You're examples for using raw pointers are contrived and not applicable to real world code.  I would like to think that we are helping people to write good *real world code* because, that's what school is (should be) for anyway, right?

Comment: There's plenty of "real world code" where the compilers/environments used are old enough that std::unique_ptr and such don't exist, and you're not allowed to bring more in.  Nothing wrong with knowing the basics.  Sometimes you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The boost library has `ptr_vector` : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html
for you which does exactly that.

`vector` itself only activates the destroctor of the objects it immediately contains. In this case, it contains a raw C pointer which does not have a destroctor.

Comment: In C++11 I would prefer a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` over importing boost into a project if it were not already there.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the documentation of ~vector() in stl_vector.h:

`The dtor only erases the elements, and note that if the
   elements themselves are pointers, the pointed-to memory is
   not touched in any way.  Managing the pointer is the user's
   responsibility.`

So, no.